# How to disallow all connection except Windows application in local ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: postgresql

My Windows application uses PostgreSQL as a repository.
When it starts, it sets an environment variable `PGPASSWORD` dynamically so it can log in without a password authentication.

@ Question

How can I disallow any local/remote connection?
I just want my Application to be able to log in.

Comment: [The pg_hba.conf File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: Yes, I know that file but do you think I can only allow the App and disallow any try in local? App and local connection tries happen in the same windows machine.

Comment: keep the password a secret.

Comment: Yes you can, on that same file you can set the database and the user to access it and disallow whatever else.

Comment: Can you please show an example?